# Electrical junction box under the sink gets wet

Tags: electrical, wet

We just purchased a house and under the kitchen sink there is a metal junction box for the electricity to the disposal switch.

It is on the bottom of the cabinet and it is covered in electrical tape.

It is possible that it can get wet when  the sink backs and it is necessary to remove the trap.

It the box location a code violation or just shoddy work?

Comment: As JRaef says, under the sink is correct but it is usually in the wall. A photo will help.  If you have to take the trap off  then you need to protect the box plus  turn off the breaker,  and use a tub to catch water left in the trap.

Comment: Your trap should have a drain plug on the very bottom for just this reason: to avoid spraying water all over when you do plumbing work.  If it doesn't, buy a new trap.

Comment: What do you mean by bottom, on the floor of the cabinet, or on the wall near the bottom of the cabinet?  If it is on the floor of the cabinet, then it is most likely a code violation.  On the wall it is ok.

Answer (score 6):

Under the sink is where it is supposed to be, but without a photo we can't tell if it was done right or not. The real problem however is more likely in your plumbing leaking and getting it wet.